# Ruby on Rails: render partial form for each user found from search results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, partials

Is it possible to render a form from a shared partial for each user I get as a search result?

So when I search for `adam`, I get something like:

Adam1 [follow form]

Adam2 [follow form]

Adam3 [follow form]

Where the follow form is a follow button that saves a relationship to the database, so each of the buttons must send a corresponding user id correctly.
All the following mechanic etc works correctly, you can follow a user when visiting his profile, but I now implemented a search for users, and when getting the results, I also want the form to be next to each result.

I believe in the view I need to do something like:

```
<% for result in @results do
  render result
  render follow_form
%>
```

or

```
<% @results.each do |f|
  render f
  render follow_form for f
%>
```

But I am not exactly sure how to do that.
Even if I manage to render the users, i cannot render the form next to them. For some reason the @user container is nil.

these are the files for search controller, and the shared forms:

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController

  def search
    query = "%#{params[:query]}%"
    @users = User.where("name LIKE ? ", query)
  end

end
```

search view

```
<%= render 'shared/search_bar' %>
<ul class="users follow">
  <%= @users.each do |f| %>
    <%= render f %>
    <%= render 'shared/endorse_form' if logged_in? %>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

In the view here /\ , the render f renders correctly the users BUT also renders something that looks like a database dump below the results containing the users data. When i add the `render shared/endorse_form` I get the error about an empty class `undefined method`id' for nil:NilClass`
in line 2 of the follow(endorse) form which looks like this:

```
<%= form_for(current_user.active_endorsements.build, remote: true) do |f| %>
  <div><%= hidden_field_tag :endorsed_id, @user.id %></div>
  <%= f.submit "Endorse", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <%= f.text_field :comment, class: 'form-control' %>
<% end %>
```

How to deal with this? ANY help will be greatly appreciated.

all the code is available at https://bitbucket.org/kramarz/pracainzynierska

Comment: The reason it's rendering "something like a database dump" is that `<%= @users.each do |f| %>` outputs the return value of `@users.each`, and `each` returns its callee, which is `@users`. That is, in addition to everything inside the loop, you're also printing the `@users` object itself because that's what `each` returns. To fix that, change `<%=` on that line to just `<%`.

Comment: @Jordan Thank you jordan! What you said makes sense! Thats a good tip to remember! Alright, so I've got the 'dump' fixed, just left to properly render the forms for each corresponding user so the 'endorse' button works and sends the correct data :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that instance variables (like `@user`) aren't passed to partials automatically, so in your `endorse_form` partial `@user` is `nil`. (Also, `@user` isn't actually the object you want—you want to use the object that's yielded in each iteration of `@users.each`.) The solution is to use the `locals` option, which lets you tell `render`, what variables you want to be available in the partial and what their names should be:

```
<%= @users.each do |user| %>
  <%= render user %>
  <%= render partial: 'shared/endorse_form', locals: { endorsed_user: user } if logged_in? %>
<% end %>
```

I've done two things here. First, I renamed `f` to `user`, since `f` doesn't really make sense as a name for a User object. (In Rails views `f` usually refers to a FormBuilder object as yielded to the block you pass to `form_for`.)

Second, I added the option `locals: { endorsed_user: user }`. This tells `render`, "I want there to be a local variable named `endorsed_user` that I can use in the partial, and I want its value to be the value of `user`," which is the User object yielded by this iteration of `each`.

Then, in your `endorse_form` partial, you'll use the local variable `endorsed_user` instead of the instance variable `@user`:

```
<%= form_for(current_user.active_endorsements.build, remote: true) do |f| %>
  <div><%= hidden_field_tag :endorsed_id, endorsed_user.id %></div>
  <%= f.submit "Endorse", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <%= f.text_field :comment, class: 'form-control' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Actually makes sense what you said Jordan. but now i'm getting
undefined local variable or method `endorsed_user' for #<#<Class:0x0

same line

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that when you have options you have to use `render partial: 'foo', ...` and not just `render 'foo', ...`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you! Alright this part might be confusing but, i am actually using a partial that renders another partial. endorse_form looks like this

`<% unless current_user?(@user) %>
  <div id="endorse_form">
  <% if current_user.endorsing?(@user) %>
    <%= render 'shared/unendorse' %>
  <% else %>
    <%= render 'shared/endorse' %>
  <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>`

Comment: So in fact, the form is in the shared/endorse, can i further pass that local from that partial to the next partials? Because i want all of them also work on the user profile. And them to change from endorse to unendorse so you can give and take it back sort of. If i change the code to use `shared/endorse` instead of `shared/endorse_form` it works correctly like it should, but then i loose the option to take that endors back, and i cant use it on the @user profile page then too. On the profile page it was using the @user to work correctly... bah im getting all lost with this now..

Comment: Yes, `endorsed_user` is just a regular Ruby variable and `render` is just a regular Ruby method, so you can pass it on as above, e.g. `render partial: 'shared/endorse', locals: { endorsed_user: endorsed_user }`.

Comment: Thanks a lot bro! That solved my problem, but also raised yet another ones (god damn it :( ) Now when i endorse someone from his profile, it works, and changes to remove button, but when clicked, it does not change back to endorse, giving the same error `undefined local variable or method `endorsed_user' for`... Also when trying to endorse from search results, lets say the 3rd result, the button changes for the first result instead of the 3rd... i give up...

 I think i will just srcap all this and just stay with the possibility to endorse only from the profile page, not search results.

Comment: i must add that the error is visible in the server logs, the database record actually gets removed.

Comment: Any luck with my case mate? :(

Comment: Alright, i've managed to fix the rendering of the correct button on search results by adding dynamically generated ID's to the div, but the main problem still persists. I don't know why i get the error `NameError (undefined local variable or method endorsed_user` when trying to UNendorse. The record gets deleted but rendering back the endorse raises an such an error. Im all out of ideas :( :( :(

Comment: I suggest posting a new question with a description of the issue you're having, including all of your updated code and the stack trace of the error.